# Why am I getting a blank page when requiring a simple file?

Tags: php

index.php

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);

require 'test.php'
echo "67890";
?>
```

test.php

```
<?php
echo "do you like butter";
?>
```

When I load index.php all I get is a blank page and 67890 isn't printed on the screen.

Comment: you missed `;` in `require 'test.php'`. try `require 'test.php';`

Comment: In addition, use an IDE. It will solve half of these syntax errors. I mean it wont solve it for you, but it will highlight it for you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

PHP is very strict in semicolons appearing in the middle. You forgot a **semicolon `;`**:

```
require 'test.php';
// ---------------^
echo "67890";
```

Always make sure to display errors by enabling the `display_errors` in the `php.ini` or by using the following piece of code in the top of the pahe:

```
<?php
    ini_set('display_errors', 1);
```

It is surprising that it didn't alert you, even though you have set to display all the errors! Crazy!

Answer (score 1):

you missed semicolon `;` in `require 'test.php'`.

```
require 'test.php';
                  ^
echo "67890";
```

try

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);

require 'test.php';
echo "67890";
?>
```